# How typescript has double generic of type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type ListenerShape<
  EventType extends string,
  EventTypeMapData extends {
    [key in EventType]: unknown;
  }
> = <E extends EventType>(data: EventTypeMapData[E]) => void;

enum EventType {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b',
}

type EventTypeMapData = {
    [EventType.A]: number,
    [EventType.B]: string,
}

type Listener = ListenerShape<EventType, EventTypeMapData>;
type AListener = Listener<EventType.A>;
```

Above `Listener` is a generic function, but typescript throw `Type 'Listener' is not generic` error. Here is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2BAdhATgZQBYENIA8AUFFAKIBuqwAKuNBAB7IoAmCUS6cKA5gDQlyVFLXoBZfABFcwXFCYt2UAN5DSAbQDWEEFB7DqdSAF0AXFACuKLSgD2AdxQBuIQF8iAPigBeKATIFZlRlSiN6TwAKVllcCzDRYwhJMBk5DTITAEpfbwo7OFZXIlRLAFtDRPpVdSgAQV8oAHJcJsFSUgAhRqaAIzaiDyJQSEqxSBS0+T81DqgMkXGIADo68ygUct6Mdo6F8MhlzvWuHgFBomHq+CRUDEablgwcfAgAxaT+MaTJ2M9XEbQOqPO7oB6IJ7od4HFZ1f5AA).

Comment: `Listener` is *defined as* some type that uses generics but doesn't in itself have a type variable. Compare the definition of `ListenerShape`, where you define type variables (`EventType` and `EventTypeMapData`) vs. the definition of `Listener` which doesn't define any type variables.

Comment: "*Above Listener is a generic function*" it isn't.

Comment: @JoachimSauer @VLAZ Thanks, I see. How should I make `Listener` is a generic function?

Comment: What should be generic about it? Do you want to sort of partially apply the generic on `ListenerShape` and supply one of the generic arguments later? Or something different?

Comment: @VLAZ I want to leave out `EventType` and `EventTypeMapData` like `type AListener = Listener<EventType.A>`  or `type BListener = Listener<EventType.B>`

Answer (score 1):

*"Above `Listener` is a generic function"* - that is somewhat true. `Listener` is a type that contains a generic function. The type itself it not generic though. So calling `Listener<EventType.A>` does not work.

You could use the following workaround:

```
const func: Listener = null!
type AListener = typeof func<EventType.A>;
// type AListener = (data: number) => void
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2BAdhATgZQBYENIA8AUFFAKIBuqwAKuNBAB7IoAmCUS6cKA5gDQlyVFLXoBZfABFcwXFCYt2UAN5DSAbQDWEEFB7DqdSAF0AXFACuKLSgD2AdxQBuIQF8iAPigBeKATIFZlRlSiN6TwAKVllcCzDRYwhJMBk5DTITAEpfbwo7OFZXIlRLAFtDRPpVdSgAQV8oAHJcJsFSUgAhRqaAIzaiDyJQSEqxSBS0%20T81DqgMkXGIADo68ygUct6Mdo6F8MhlzvWuHgFBomHq%20CRUDEablgwcfAgAxaT%20MaTJ2M9igDGdhQSCgADNrACLI87uhGpsADYIgCEV1GdRhaDhfhGEDsYPBkPeBxWdX%20RAA9BSoLj6pj7n5orELJsytt0DkfHkCqwgA)

Comment: It works, but is there another graceful syntax?

Comment: @Mebtte - I am not really sure. You could put the `typeof func<EventType.A>` in its own generic type: https://tsplay.dev/WJ5b5m

Comment: @Mebtte - or you could make `Listener` a generic type (without being a generic function): https://tsplay.dev/wjQB1W

Comment: It's verbose so I don't want it.